# Magento2: Install Urdu Language Pack

Tags: magento2, language-package

I want to install urdu Langauage pack 
follow this [tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-urdu-language-pack.html)

running this command :

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ur_PK

give this Error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   ur_PK argument has invalid value, please run info:language:list for
>   list of available locales

Comment: What happens when you run `php bin/magento info:language:list`?

Comment: Urdu language not available .

Answer (score 0):

No sorry not working for me neither.

Reach out to Mageplaza

```
user@cli:/var/www/magento# composer require mageplaza/magento-2-urdu-language-pack:dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing mageplaza/module-core (1.4.4): Cloning 8d50d27c1b from cache
  - Installing mageplaza/magento-2-urdu-language-pack (dev-master 8498cd3): Cloning 8498cd3d94 from cache
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
user@cli:/var/www/magento#
```

And then

```
user@cli:/var/www/magento# php bin/magento info:language:list
+--------------------------------+------------+
| Language                       | Code       |
+--------------------------------+------------+
| Afrikaans (South Africa)       | af_ZA      |
| Albanian (Albania)             | sq_AL      |
| Arabic (Algeria)               | ar_DZ      |
| Arabic (Egypt)                 | ar_EG      |
| Arabic (Kuwait)                | ar_KW      |
| Arabic (Morocco)               | ar_MA      |
| Arabic (Saudi Arabia)          | ar_SA      |
| Azerbaijani (Azerbaijan)       | az_Latn_AZ |
| Basque (Spain)                 | eu_ES      |
| Belarusian (Belarus)           | be_BY      |
| Bengali (Bangladesh)           | bn_BD      |
| Bosnian (Bosnia & Herzegovina) | bs_Latn_BA |
| Bulgarian (Bulgaria)           | bg_BG      |
| Catalan (Spain)                | ca_ES      |
| Chinese (China)                | zh_Hans_CN |
| Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China)  | zh_Hant_HK |
| Chinese (Taiwan)               | zh_Hant_TW |
| Croatian (Croatia)             | hr_HR      |
| Czech (Czech Republic)         | cs_CZ      |
| Danish (Denmark)               | da_DK      |
| Dutch (Belgium)                | nl_BE      |
| Dutch (Netherlands)            | nl_NL      |
| English (Australia)            | en_AU      |
| English (Canada)               | en_CA      |
| English (Ireland)              | en_IE      |
| English (New Zealand)          | en_NZ      |
| English (United Kingdom)       | en_GB      |
| English (United States)        | en_US      |
| Estonian (Estonia)             | et_EE      |
| Filipino (Philippines)         | fil_PH     |
| Finnish (Finland)              | fi_FI      |
| French (Belgium)               | fr_BE      |
| French (Canada)                | fr_CA      |
| French (France)                | fr_FR      |
| French (Luxembourg)            | fr_LU      |
| French (Switzerland)           | fr_CH      |
| Galician (Spain)               | gl_ES      |
| Georgian (Georgia)             | ka_GE      |
| German (Austria)               | de_AT      |
| German (Germany)               | de_DE      |
| German (Luxembourg)            | de_LU      |
| German (Switzerland)           | de_CH      |
| Greek (Greece)                 | el_GR      |
| Gujarati (India)               | gu_IN      |
| Hebrew (Israel)                | he_IL      |
| Hindi (India)                  | hi_IN      |
| Hungarian (Hungary)            | hu_HU      |
| Icelandic (Iceland)            | is_IS      |
| Indonesian (Indonesia)         | id_ID      |
| Italian (Italy)                | it_IT      |
| Italian (Switzerland)          | it_CH      |
| Japanese (Japan)               | ja_JP      |
| Khmer (Cambodia)               | km_KH      |
| Korean (South Korea)           | ko_KR      |
| Lao (Laos)                     | lo_LA      |
| Latvian (Latvia)               | lv_LV      |
| Lithuanian (Lithuania)         | lt_LT      |
| Macedonian (Macedonia)         | mk_MK      |
| Malay (Malaysia)               | ms_MY      |
| Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)      | nb_NO      |
| Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)     | nn_NO      |
| Persian (Iran)                 | fa_IR      |
| Polish (Poland)                | pl_PL      |
| Portuguese (Brazil)            | pt_BR      |
| Portuguese (Portugal)          | pt_PT      |
| Romanian (Romania)             | ro_RO      |
| Russian (Russia)               | ru_RU      |
| Serbian (Serbia)               | sr_Cyrl_RS |
| Slovak (Slovakia)              | sk_SK      |
| Slovenian (Slovenia)           | sl_SI      |
| Spanish (Argentina)            | es_AR      |
| Spanish (Bolivia)              | es_BO      |
| Spanish (Chile)                | es_CL      |
| Spanish (Colombia)             | es_CO      |
| Spanish (Costa Rica)           | es_CR      |
| Spanish (Mexico)               | es_MX      |
| Spanish (Panama)               | es_PA      |
| Spanish (Peru)                 | es_PE      |
| Spanish (Spain)                | es_ES      |
| Spanish (Venezuela)            | es_VE      |
| Swahili (Kenya)                | sw_KE      |
| Swedish (Finland)              | sv_FI      |
| Swedish (Sweden)               | sv_SE      |
| Thai (Thailand)                | th_TH      |
| Turkish (Turkey)               | tr_TR      |
| Ukrainian (Ukraine)            | uk_UA      |
| Vietnamese (Vietnam)           | vi_VN      |
| Welsh (United Kingdom)         | cy_GB      |
+--------------------------------+------------+
```

Did `setup:upgrade` and seeing `Mageplaza_Core`

Comment: what is the issue ? same here.

Comment: Not installing correctly

Comment: Then how can i install Urdu language pack?

Comment: Not using this. That's the reason for the error though. The language pack not installing results in the InvalidArgumentException error

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?